# Adding Monolog to PHP 5.6 Project

Tags: php, monolog

Im trying to add Monolog to a project which is running PHP version 5.6.3 and therefore its detecting the version and reverting.

On the documentation it saying

> use Monolog ^1.0 for PHP 5.3+ support.

But I dont understand how is accomplished as a composer command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line in your `composer.json` file (in `require` section):

```
"monolog/monolog": "^1.0"
```

Then run `composer install` and you should be good to go!